# Console.log is not working on my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and for one of my components, there is a button and when clicked on, it runs a function "myFunction" which simply runs a console.log command.
[image]
When I compile my code, no errors arise on either my Visual Studio or my browser. However, nothing happens when I click the button in question. I have checked the web browser's console and the updated code is been reflected on the browser ..... but still, the button doesn't perform the console.log when clicked.

Can you please, please help?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as an image :) And shouldn't it be `onClick` ?

Answer (score 2):

In react click event prop should be written as **onClick**(C in uppercase) instead of **onclick**.

Answer (score 0):

Write your onclick function in camelcase -- onClick. Standard React naming convention. You may also want a more specific function name, like handleClick(e).